# How to I reorder get_post_types() results alphabetically in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, alphabetical

I'm able to output a list of my custom post types using the code below. How can I order the results alphabetically?

```
$args = array(
'public'   => true,
'_builtin' => false,
);
$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 
foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {
$pts = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
$post_title = $pts->labels->name;
echo '<li><a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type ) . '">' . $post_title . '</a></li>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use PHP to sort the values of the returned array, instead of requesting a sorted list from WordPress itself.

```
$args = array(
'public'   => true,
'_builtin' => false,
);
$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'
$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator );
asort( $post_types ); // the array is passed by reference, not assignment
// then loop your [now sorted] results
```

The `asort` function will maintain the key association. If you want it to re-index the array, use `sort` instead.